# making a video by Matlab style plot functions for OpenCV

Tags: opencv

Can I make a video by Matlab style plot functions for OpenCV ? I found the code 
https://code.google.com/p/cvplot/

Comment: if you use OpenCV with the python interface you can use the python package matplotlib which plots graphs with an api similar to matlab.